# What will be the direction of the induced current in the loop due to the other loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

Say I have a circular loop in which current is flowing which is being increased as time passes by. And beside it in the same plane there is another circular loop which isn't connected to any circuit. Now due to the current carrying loop a magnetic field will be generated which will be time varying, right ? And due to this field, a current will be induced in the other loop, so what will be the direction of current in it ? I couldn't determine the direction as I was unable to determine the direction of the magnetic field due to the current carrying loop on the other loop. Will I have to do some calculus to find out ? Because, it isn't trivial to me where the direction of the magnetic field due to the time varying current will be for the other loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction of the magnetic field generated by a loop in which current is flowing is given by the right hand rule
[image]

Therefore the magnetic field through the second loop will be
[image]

If the current inside the first loop increases so does the magnetic field it generates, and so does the magnetic flux through the second loop. By induction this changing magnetic flux through the second loop will generate a current in it, whose direction will be given by [Lenz's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law). This law says that the direction of the induced current is such to produce a magnetic field that opposes the change in the inducing magnetic flux. Since the inducing magnetic field is increasing, and "from top to bottom" in the figure, the current must generate a field "from bottom to top". But the right hand rule again then tells you that the direction of the current must be the same of the first loop:
[image]

Comment: The statement of Lenz' Law in this answer is incorrect.  The induced field acts to oppose *changes* in the field, not the field itself.

Comment: The direction of the current in 2 is correctly shown, but only by luck.  If the current in 1 were decreasing, the logic of this answer predicts the current in 2 would be as shown. However,    Lenz' Law says that the induced field would act to "try" to maintain the field, that is, the induced field would point down, and the induced current in 2 would be opposite to that shown.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer